# How to apply dragging to all elements within Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there any setting/framework that can help to drag text, images and videos smoothly within ckeditor?

From dragging, I mean to drag/position all elements anywhere I want them to be.

Comment: See [this issue](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11437) on CKEditor's bug tracker. The feature is under construction at the moment.